# What does "con piu fuoco possibile" mean?

Tags: terminology, tempo

Towards the end of Chopin's Etude No. 4 in C# minor, Op. 10 No. 4, it says **"con più fuoco possibile."** What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Definition of con fuoco
: FIERILY, IMPETUOUSLY —used as a direction in music**

possibile = **as possible**

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/con%20fuoco

*Con fuoco Definition and background:A musical directive to the performer to play a particular passage with vehement energy or fervid emotion. with fire, in a fiery manner*

**this means: most fierly**

but not hot sexy!

this was only con fuoco! you can't imagine like it would be:

con piu fuoco possibile piu = even more!

**edit! the commentors are right:**

this conductor explains much better

what con fuoco means:

Comment: That has to be the sickest interpretation of Dvorak I've ever seen.  Eye bleach please!  (and in all seriousness, that team lap dance would go with any 2/4 or 4/4 tune)

Comment: I actually find Dvorak's 9-4 to be triumphant and heroic, as if I were in a war between a large amount of villains and I have triumphed over them.

Comment: Second YouTube link is dead. No description, so can't find a replacement.

Comment: @Aaron If you google the end of the youtube link, you can usually find mirrors on facebook and shady Russian-hosted websites.  It looks like that one pointed to "Gustavo Dudamel _ Dvorak - Symphony no. 9 - 4th movement - Allegro con fuoco".

Answer (score 10):

Word by word:

- con - with
- più - more
- fuoco - fire
- possibile - possible

In Italian, "possibile" stuck on the end of a phrase means "as much [preceding thing] as possible".

So translated as a phrase: "With as much fire as possible"